# Program error; need advice

Tags: c++

Generally I have a class named "person" and its methods, print: to print the data, and is_better_than to find some max numbers. I cannot understand what is the problem. Any advice?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

class person
{
    private:
        string name;
        double weight;
        double height;

    public:
        person(); //Constructor

        bool is_better_than(person best);
        void read();
        void print();

        void operator=(const person& b); //overloading operator
};

person::person()
 {
    string name = "";
    double weight = 0;
    double height = 0;
 }

 void person::print()
{
    cout << name << "\nWeight: " << weight << "\nHeight: " << height << "\n";
}

void person::read()
{
    cout << "Please enter person's name: ";
    getline(cin, this->name);
    cout << "Please enter person's weight: ";
    cin >> this->weight;
    cout << "Please enter person's height: ";
    cin >> this->height;

    string remainder;
    getline(cin, remainder); //clear the buffer
}

bool person::is_better_than(person best)
{
    if ((this->weight / pow(this->height,2) >= best.weight / (pow(best.height,2))) || best.weight == 0)
        return true;

    return false;
}

// iperfortosi telesti =
void person::operator=(const person & b)
{
    this->name = b.name;
    this->weight = b.weight;
    this->height = b.height;
}

int main()
{
    person maxBMI;
    bool cont = true;
    while (cont)
    {
        person newperson;
        newperson.read();

        if (newperson.is_better_than(maxBMI))
            maxBMI = newperson;

        cout << "More data? (y/n) ";
        string answer;
        getline(cin, answer);

        if (answer != "y")
            cont = false;
    }
    cout << "The person with maximum BMI (body mass index) is ";
    maxBMI.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Please enter person's name: Name
Please enter person's weight: 123
Please enter person's height: 123
More data? (y/n) n
The person with maximum BMI (body mass index) is
Weight: 1.7881e-307
Height: 2.0746e-317
```

Comment: I guess the Weight and Height for him show up weirdly which he was not expecting.

Comment: I get wrong output

Comment: My advice is to use a *debugger* and single step through each instruction, *watching* the values of variables.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results in Visual Studio 2015 (neither debug/release nor x86/x64). I recommend you step through your program in the debugger to see where execution goes wrong.

Comment: Change weight and height to integral values.  Choose smaller units as possible.  For example, if height is in meters, make it integral and use millimeters.

Comment: Declare your `is_better_than` method to pass by constant reference and since the method doesn't change any members, declare the method as `const`.  You should develop the habit of *const correctness* early in you learning to help you reduce the number of injected defects and making your program more correct.

Comment: The constructor initialization does not work. Your code will not fail because of this though. Change `person::person()
 {
    string name = "";
    double weight = 0;
    double height = 0;
 }` to `person::person()
 {
    string name = "";
    weight = 0.0;
    height = 0.0;
 }

Comment: I use xcode and don't see any problem either. Can you specify what compiler you are using.

Comment: Use initialization list in your constructor:  `person::person() : name(""), weight(0.0), height(0.0) { };`

Comment: Okay thank you! I changed the constructor to person::person()
 {
  name = "";
 weight = 0.0;
 height = 0.0;
 }
and it does work now

Comment: Get in the habit of not using the `this->` notation.  C++ is not Java.  C++ is not C#.  If you need to use `this->` it is because your parameter names are the same as your member names.  Change the parameter names.

Comment: Is there any problem? I tested this on linux and mac using clang and gcc both.

Comment: If i remove all the "this->" will my program still work the same as with it?

Comment: Prefer to use `x * x` instead of `pow(x,2)`.  The `pow` function has a calling overhead and must go through an algorithm.  The `x * x` only uses a couple of instructions (since most processors have a multiply instruction).  Much more efficient, less code, less chance of bugs.

Comment: You don't need `this->`.  It is assumed by the compiler when you access members directly.

Comment: You may want to `transform` your input from the user to all upper case or all lower case before comparing.  Search the internet for "c++ string transform tolower", this eliminates the need for two compares:  lower case and upper case.

Comment: Is your wrong output due to the formatting of the floating point numbers?  Please **edit** your post with the expected output.

Comment: @max66:  If you don't define a copy constructor, the compiler will generate one for you (with member-by-member copy).  In this case, this will do exactly the right thing.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews:  I disagree with "don't use `this->`" - explicit is always better than implicit (and with a decent IDE it makes writing the code much easier).  I also don't think there is much benefit to make height and weight be integer rather than float (float makes handling input in imperial units much easier for example).

Comment: @MartinBonner: Why is `this->` syntax more explicit?  When using member variable names, that is about as explicit as you can get.  I change the names in my method parameters to avoid confusion with data members.  I also use a naming convention for member names, such as "m_" prefix, to help differentiate member names from parameter names.  Also, using `this->` involves more typing which can inject more defects into the code.

Comment: @ Martin Bonner - obviously I'm out of phase: I knew perfetly about the member-by-member-copy. Thanks for the correction; I delete immediately my monstruosity.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: <shrug>  It's a stylistic question; there is no one correct answer.  Your initial comment to the OP was rather dogmatic - I thought  it was worth pointing out that there are other views.  (Particularly as it really *is* worth the OP getting into the habit of using member initializer lists and const correctness)

Answer (score 1):

Your default constructor does not work because it assigns to local variables and not to class variables. It should look like this:

```
person::person()
{
    name = "";
    weight = 0;
    height = 0;
}
```

or better:

```
person::person() : name(""), weight(0.0), height(0.0) {}
```

With your default constructor, the class attributes remain uninitialized and the assumption that `best.weight`is initially zero, does not work.

Comment: He does need a default constructor.  name doesn't need constructing, but height and weight do.

Comment: This is the second time I have seen this mistake (local variables in constructor) today on SO.  Has some new book/website come out that is confusing, or is it just one instructor.

Comment: @MartinBonner, oh, there had been coincidences much much tougher. :)